# Yii2: How to load model in component?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am beginner in Yii2 basic. I have done this code in Yii 1.1. This is working working fine in Yii 1. But unable to load model in yii2.

Please check my code:

`components/UserFun.php`

```
<?php
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Component;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class UserFun extends Component {
    public function getStudioId($params = '') {
        $studio = Studio::find()->where("id=:id",[':id' => $studio_id]); /* Skipped rest code */
        return $studio->id;
    }
}
```

Above my code I am getting this error.

> ## PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> #### Class 'app\components\Studio' not found

Please help me

Comment: assuming your Studio is a model object, you should either
 use app\models\Studio
or 
app\models\Studio::find()->where([])->all();

Comment: @Gunnrryy I have added it. getting this error `Class 'app\models\Studio' not found`

Comment: can you paste the location of your Studio class?
you need to use {Namespace}."\".{ClassName}::find()->....

Comment: @Gunnrryy Sorry dear, I have missed namespace of my `Studio.php` model. Thats why that error was coming. thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to include you `Studio` model first.

like `use frontend\models\Studio;` or whatever your model namespace is.

In `Yii1` it was a different story, because there was no namespaces.

Comment: I am not using advanced. Also I have included `use yii\base\Model;`

Comment: It's the same for basic. Load your model first from namespace you defined (probably `use app\models\Studio;`)   - `yii\base\Model;` is the model your `Studio` model probably extends and not the model you need right there

Comment: Yes I followed your answer.  and getting another error `Class 'app\models\Studio' not found`

Comment: So is there class named `Studio` in  file named `Studio.php` under that namespace? Where is your `Studio` file and class? Under which namespace?

Comment: Yes, I have missed `namespace` in my `Studio.php` model. Thanks for your answering.